# How to convert an image sequence to multiple mp4 video files?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image sequence of a 2500 frames and I would like to convert it to 100 mp4 files

```
1-25 -- myvid_001.mp4
26-50 -- myvid_002.mp4
50-75 -- myvid_003.mp4
76-100 -- myvid_003.mp4
...
```

Each video is 25 fps and a second long.

I can convert a long video sequence to many smaller videos, but, I assumed it may be a better way to directly produce the small video clips from the sequence source.

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1: [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i %04d.jpg -f segment -segment_time 1 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 -g 25 -vf format=yuv420p myvid_%03d.mp4
```

This assumes your inputs are `0001.jpg`, `0002.jpg`, etc.

## Method 2: [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i %04d.jpg -frames:v 25 -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart myvid_001.mp4
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -start_number 26 -i %04d.jpg -frames:v 24 -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart myvid_002.mp4
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -start_number 51 -i %04d.jpg -frames:v 24 -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart myvid_003.mp4
...
```